# Select2 triggering change event

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, jquery-select2, html-select

I, not so long ago, went ahead and built an html dependent dropdown which pulls it's data from an array in the js. The dependencies worked perfectly fine until I realized that I needed to add a search function to the dropdown.

I went through different alternatives and to me the simplest option was to use select2 plugin. The problem I am having is that when using select2, it doesn't seem to be triggering the EventListener (Line 43 in JS) I had previously setup for the regular select.

Find below what I have attempted:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>


</head>
<body>
    <select id ="level1"  style='width: 300px;'></select>
    <select id ="level2"  style='width: 300px;'></select>
    <select id ="level3"  style='width: 300px;'></select>
    <hr>
    
    <select id ="level4" disabled></select>
    <select id ="level5" disabled></select>
    <select id ="level6" disabled></select>
    <select id ="level7" disabled></select>
    <hr>
    <h1 id ="level8"></h1>

    <script src="betterdd.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS: (Select options are found in var myData = [...])

```
class DropDown {

    constructor(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.targets = [];
    }

    filterData(filtersAsArray){
        return this.data.filter(r => filtersAsArray.every((item,i) => item === r[i]));
    }

    getUniqueValues(dataAsArray,index){
        const uniqueOptions = new Set();
        dataAsArray.forEach(r => uniqueOptions.add(r[index]));
        return [...uniqueOptions];
    }

    populateDropDown(el,listAsArray){
        el.innerHTML = "";
    
        listAsArray.forEach(item => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.textContent = item;
            el.appendChild(option);
        });
    }

    createPopulateDropDownFunction(el,elsDependsOn){
        return () => {
        const elsDependsOnValues = elsDependsOn.length === 0 ? null : elsDependsOn.map(depEl => depEl.value);
        const dataToUse = elsDependsOn.length === 0 ? this.data : this.filterData (elsDependsOnValues);
        const listToUse = this.getUniqueValues(dataToUse, elsDependsOn.length); 
        this.populateDropDown(el,listToUse);
        }
    }

    add(options){
        //{target: "level2", dependsOn: ["level1"] }
        const el = document.getElementById(options.target);
        const elsDependsOn = options.dependsOn.length === 0 ? [] : options.dependsOn.map(id => document.getElementById(id));
        const eventFunction = this.createPopulateDropDownFunction (el, elsDependsOn);
        const targetObject = { el: el, elsDependsOn: elsDependsOn,func: eventFunction};
        targetObject.elsDependsOn.forEach(depEl => depEl.addEventListener("change",eventFunction));
        this.targets.push(targetObject);
        return this;
    }

    initialize(){
        this.targets.forEach(t => t.func());
        return this;
    }

    eazyDropDown(arrayOfIds){
        arrayOfIds.forEach((item,i) =>{
            const option = {target: item, dependsOn: arrayOfIds.slice(0,i) }
            this.add(option);
        });
        this.initialize();
        return this;
    }

}
var dd = new DropDown(myData).eazyDropDown(["level1","level2","level3","level4","level5","level6","level7","level8"])
```

Answer (score 1):

add the following line inside **add** method  :

```
const eventFunction = this.createPopulateDropDownFunction (el, elsDependsOn);
el.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    eventFunction();
    console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

and remove the following line:

```
targetObject.elsDependsOn.forEach(depEl => depEl.addEventListener("change",eventFunction));
```

Comment: Trying this didn't seem to trigger the eventFunction. I tried implementing a simple alert () and it didn't seem to trigger it.

Reading up a little further I found the following to trigger the alert:
```
        $("select").change(function() {
           alert("hello")
        });
```
Although I was unable to implement it in the method.

@Raul.F